# SAE J1939 Standards Collection -- How much is necessary?

Tags: c, embedded, j1939

I'm developing an application that will be communicating with a vehicle via J1939.  My plan is to purchase a J1939 stack, so I'm reasonably certain that I won't need to get the standards for the Physical Layer or the Data Link Layer, but I'd like to know how much of the various Application Layers I should order from SAE?

I think I need:

- J1939-71 Vehicle Application Layer
- J1939-73 Application Layer Diagnostics
- J1939-74 Application - Configurable Messaging

But I'd love to know what others have found useful while implementing the application side of things.

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: However, according to my experiences with gought stacks, I would not bet on **not** having to dig into the subject deeper than you actually wanted to.

Comment: You'll probably need -21 (Data Link Layer). I can only echo what Olaf says above, even if you buy a stack from a vendor who promises full compliance, chances are you'll end up digging through the spec sooner or later.

Comment: Apologies for the off topic-ness!  I've been asked create the ability to send a data set from our device to a host over J1939, but the data parameters (SPNs) and messages (PGNs) have not been defined.  I wanted to know where in the SAE standards for J1939 I could find direction on creating / finding suitable messages, and hopefully find existing messages that I could reuse.

Answer (score 1):

I would add at least **SAE J1939-21** to your list. It describes the data link layer using the CAN protocol with 29-bit Identifiers.

I would point you attention to **Transport Protocol Connection Management** described in this document.  If you want to work with diagnostics layer you should be able to handle **Broadcast Announce Messages** because DM1 message will not be broadcasted if thre are more then one Diagnostic Trouble Code on the same Warning Lamp.